# VBA out of memory issue with range

Tags: vba

When I try to run the code below in my PC it is working fine. However it is not working fine when I try to run in another PC.

I need to deploy the tool.

```
'I am getting error here
ws2.columns(2).insert
ws2.range("A:A").value = ws3.range("C:C").value
```

Comment: What is the specific error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding parameters to your insert?

Like this :

```
ws2.Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ws2.Range("A:A").Value = ws3.Range("C:C").Value
```

Or directly insert your colum, like this :

```
ws3.Range("C:C").Copy
ws2.Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```